# pythonic way to collect specific data from complex dict

Tags: coding-style, python

i need to collect some data from complext dict based on Dot Notation key names

for example

**sample data**

```
data = {
  'name': {'last': 'smith', 'first': 'bob'},
  'address':{'city': 'NY', 'state': 'NY'},
  'contact':{'phone':{'self':'1234', 'home':'222'}},
  'age':38,
  'other':'etc'
}

keys = ['contact.phone.self', 'name.last', 'age']
```

**my logic**

```
result = []
for rev_key in rev_keys:  
  current = data.copy()   
  rev_key = rev_key.split('.')  
  while rev_key:  
    value = rev_key.pop(0)  
    current = current[value]  
  result.append(current)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Never use a class name as a variable name.  Please fix the example to avoid using `dict` as a variable.  It's a dreadful mistake.

Answer (score 4):

```
[reduce(dict.get, key.split("."), data) for key in keys]
```

Comment: pfffiuu ! I hardly understood how reduce() works on a dictionary, but I finaly got it. Admirable solution. +1 is not enough

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
def fetch( some_dict, key_iter ):
    for key in key_iter:
        subdict= some_dict
        for field in key.split('.'):
            subdict = subdict[field]
        yield subdict

a_dict = {
  'name': {'last': 'smith', 'first': 'bob'},
  'address':{'city': 'NY', 'state': 'NY'},
  'contact':{'phone':{'self':'1234', 'home':'222'}},
  'age':38,
  'other':'etc'
}

keys = ['contact.phone.self', 'name.last', 'age']

result = list( fetch( a_dict, keys ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my crack at it:

```
>>> def find(tree,cur):
    if len(cur)==1:
        return tree[cur[0]]
    else:
        return find(tree[cur[0]],cur[1:])


>>> print [find(data,k.split(".")) for k in keys]
['1234', 'smith', 38]
```

Of course this will cause stack overflows if the items are too deeply nested (unless you explicitly raise the recursion depth), and I would use a `deque` instead of a `list` if this were production code.

Answer (score 0):

Just write a function that gets one key at a time

```
def getdottedkey(data, dottedkey):
    for key in dottedkey.split('.'):
        data = data[key]
    return data

print [getdottedkey(data, k) for k in keys]
```